# Approach while learning Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, towers-of-hanoi

I am learning algorithms and came to this Hanoi Tower. I know how to do that practically. But I am unable to code it. I haven't read the given code yet. I am trying it first myself. What should be my approach-keep trying or read the given code or something else?

Should this approach be followed with all the algorithms?

Comment: I know it is not a good question but I don't think it doesn't deserve an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this useful:

http://www.quora.com/Algorithms/How-does-one-become-good-at-solving-algorithm-programming-problems

A big takeaway from the post above:

> Popular to contrary belief, I don't think coding solutions to
>   algorithmic problems is a generally effective way to learn algorithms.
>   The people who have done it successfully though are usually good/quick
>   at spotting patterns and solving algorithmically oriented problems.
>
> You need not actually write code to solve an example problem - just
>   make sure you understand the underlying idea for solving it.

Answer (score 0):

Watch this -

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFJhEPrbycQ&list=SPFE6E58F856038C69

If you had 3 rings, how would you move the entire tower?  Move the first top 2 rings to the temporary ring. Move the bottom ring to the destination. Then copy the 2 rings from the temp to the final.

The key to understand this is recursion and think about moving N-1 rings